# How to combine two menu's in Drupal

Tags: routes, theming

I'm building a site with 2 menu's. One is the main menu, the other one is similar to the user menu.

The user menu is only displayed in a panel on the frontpage, the main menu is always visible. To keep the user-menu options available I'd like to add them to the main menu as well so they are always accessible too.

I thought of appending the user-menu to the main-menu in my custom template.php like below, but that gave me just the main-menu.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['main_menu'] = array_merge(menu_main_menu(), menu_navigation_links('menu-myoptions'));
}
```

I was using the main-menu-block, so I thought that could be the reason the altered menu is not showing up. (The block might load the menu directly).
But when I user `render($main_menu)` in my page.tpl.php it doesn't work eighter.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Menu Minipanels](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels).

> A system for building "megamenu" -style dropdown menus
>   using Mini Panels, which provides tremendous flexibility in what can
>   be displayed.
>
> Click-by-click beginner's tutorial:
>   http://drupal.org/node/984560#comment-3922442

It allowed to me to create a [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) lay-out and place the menu-blocks I wanted in there. To front-end users it looks like it is one menu.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can try this [Advanced Menu](https://drupal.org/project/advanced_menu) module, Menus can now be merged into other menus. This allows users with the appropriate permission to add links to other menus which are then displayed as if there were a single menu.

> Example:
>
> Create new role "News Manager"
>
> Create new user "News Editor"
>
> Create new menu "News Releases", Set "News Manager" as an editor for
>   the menu.

Comment: That looked promising, but after enabling it broke the menu leaving only 2 links. I'll have a look at the issue queue tomorrow. Thanks :)